# React Native iOS App Crashes "EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)" on iOS 11.3 with xcode 9.0

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native, crash

I have tried exported my app to iOS10.2 and it works fine. But when I exported it to iOS11.3 and open a certain WebView it crashes after a while.

I have tried using the same WebView with another URL and it works fine.

Please tell me how can I modify the layout so that it will not crash on iOS11.3 or later?

```html
Incident Identifier: 288A0B32-02D3-4293-A60B-C705FC3C0265
CrashReporter 
Key:   

Hardware Model:      iPhone9,1
Process:             HealthCheck [506]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/CC8E784E-60FA-4008-A129-418DD95248E7/HealthCheck.app/HealthCheck
Identifier:          
Version:             1 (1.0)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:            [615]


Date/Time:           2018-04-13 10:51:33.2295 +0800
Launch Time:         2018-04-13 10:36:20.1999 +0800
OS Version:          iPhone OS 11.3 (15E216)
Baseband Version:    3.66.00
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x000000018afb0d3c
Termination Signal: Trace/BPT trap: 5
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x5
Terminating Process: exc handler [0]
Triggered by Thread:  4

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00000001816c3e08 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00000001816c3c80 mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                 0x0000000181c06e40 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3   CoreFoundation                 0x0000000181c04908 __CFRunLoopRun + 1568
4   CoreFoundation                 0x0000000181b24da8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 552
5   GraphicsServices               0x0000000183b07020 GSEventRunModal + 100
6   UIKit                          0x000000018bb0578c UIApplicationMain + 236
7   HealthCheck                    0x0000000104fcede8 main + 28136 (__hidden#17_:16)
8   libdyld.dylib                  0x00000001815b5fc0 start + 4

Thread 1 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00000001816c3e08 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00000001816c3c80 mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                 0x0000000181c06e40 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3   CoreFoundation                 0x0000000181c04908 __CFRunLoopRun + 1568
4   CoreFoundation                 0x0000000181b24da8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 552
5   Foundation                     0x0000000182599674 -[NSRunLoop+ 34420 (NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 304
6   Foundation                     0x000000018259951c -[NSRunLoop+ 34076 (NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 148
7   UIKit                          0x000000018b7ea7e4 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 136
8   Foundation                     0x00000001826a9efc __NSThread__start__ + 1040
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000181885220 _pthread_body + 272
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000181885110 _pthread_body + 0
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000181883b10 thread_start + 4

Thread 2 name:  com.facebook.react.JavaScript
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00000001816c3e08 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00000001816c3c80 mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                 0x0000000181c06e40 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3   CoreFoundation                 0x0000000181c04908 __CFRunLoopRun + 1568
4   CoreFoundation                 0x0000000181b24da8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 552
5   HealthCheck                    0x0000000104fdf7b0 _hidden#984_ + 96176 (__hidden#1374_:248)
6   Foundation                     0x00000001826a9efc __NSThread__start__ + 1040
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000181885220 _pthread_body + 272
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000181885110 _pthread_body + 0
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000181883b10 thread_start + 4

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00000001816e50f4 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000181887c90 _pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$mp + 644
2   libc++.1.dylib                 0x0000000180d9c2ec std::__1::condition_variable::__do_timed_wait+ 29420 (std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&, std::__1::chrono::time_point<std::__1::chrono::system_clock, std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > >) + 96
3   JavaScriptCore                 0x000000018927b430 std::__1::cv_status std::__1::condition_variable::wait_until<std::__1::chrono::steady_clock, std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > >+ 11252784 (std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&, std::__1::chrono::time_point<std::__1::chrono::steady_clock, std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > > const&) + 124
4   JavaScriptCore                 0x000000018927b2e0 std::__1::cv_status std::__1::condition_variable_any::wait_until<std::__1::unique_lock<bmalloc::Mutex>, std::__1::chrono::steady_clock, std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > >+ 11252448 (std::__1::unique_lock<bmalloc::Mutex>&, std::__1::chrono::time_point<std::__1::chrono::steady_clock, std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > > const&) + 112
5   JavaScriptCore                 0x000000018927ae24 bmalloc::Scavenger::threadRunLoop+ 11251236 () + 272
6   JavaScriptCore                 0x000000018927ab60 bmalloc::Scavenger::Scavenger+ 11250528 (std::__1::lock_guard<bmalloc::StaticMutex>&) + 0
7   JavaScriptCore                 0x000000018927af7c void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::__thread_struct> >, void (*)(bmalloc::Scavenger*), bmalloc::Scavenger*> >+ 11251580 (void*) + 44
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000181885220 _pthread_body + 272
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000181885110 _pthread_body + 0
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000181883b10 thread_start + 4

Thread 4 name:  WebThread
Thread 4 Crashed:
0   WebCore                        0x000000018afb0d3c bmalloc::IsoAllocator<bmalloc::IsoConfig<232u> >::allocateSlow+ 19135804 (bool) + 264
1   WebCore                        0x000000018afb0c7c bmalloc::IsoAllocator<bmalloc::IsoConfig<232u> >::allocateSlow+ 19135612 (bool) + 72
2   WebCore                        0x000000018afb1bb0 WebCore::RenderElement::createFor+ 19139504 (WebCore::Element&, WebCore::RenderStyle&&, WebCore::RenderElement::RendererCreationType) + 772
3   WebCore                        0x000000018b0f8774 WebCore::RenderTreeUpdater::createRenderer+ 20477812 (WebCore::Element&, WebCore::RenderStyle&&) + 644
4   WebCore                        0x000000018b0f6c68 WebCore::RenderTreeUpdater::updateElementRenderer+ 20470888 (WebCore::Element&, WebCore::Style::ElementUpdate const&) + 656
5   WebCore                        0x000000018b0f5cc0 WebCore::RenderTreeUpdater::updateRenderTree+ 20466880 (WebCore::ContainerNode&) + 1164
6   WebCore                        0x000000018b0f5754 WebCore::RenderTreeUpdater::commit+ 20465492 (std::__1::unique_ptr<WebCore::Style::Update const, std::__1::default_delete<WebCore::Style::Update const> >) + 584
7   WebCore                        0x000000018a9aa9c4 WebCore::Document::resolveStyle+ 12818884 (WebCore::Document::ResolveStyleType) + 796
8   WebCore                        0x0000000189dc8580 WebCore::Document::updateStyleIfNeeded+ 357760 () + 228
9   WebCore                        0x000000018ad454e4 WebCore::LayoutContext::layout+ 16598244 () + 792
10  WebCore                        0x0000000189d7fff0 WebCore::ThreadTimers::sharedTimerFiredInternal+ 61424 () + 352
11  WebCore                        0x0000000189d7fe7c WebCore::timerFired+ 61052 (__CFRunLoopTimer*, void*) + 28
12  CoreFoundation                 0x0000000181c07aa8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 28
13  CoreFoundation                 0x0000000181c0776c __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 864
14  CoreFoundation                 0x0000000181c07010 __CFRunLoopDoTimers + 248
15  CoreFoundation                 0x0000000181c04b60 __CFRunLoopRun + 2168
16  CoreFoundation                 0x0000000181b24da8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 552
17  WebCore                        0x0000000189db1dcc RunWebThread+ 265676 (void*) + 592
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000181885220 _pthread_body + 272
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000181885110 _pthread_body + 0
20  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000181883b10 thread_start + 4

Thread 5 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00000001816c3e08 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00000001816c3c80 mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                 0x0000000181c06e40 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3   CoreFoundation                 0x0000000181c04908 __CFRunLoopRun + 1568
4   CoreFoundation                 0x0000000181b24da8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 552
5   CFNetwork                      0x00000001824324b0 -[__CoreSchedulingSetRunnable runForever] + 220
6   Foundation                     0x00000001826a9efc __NSThread__start__ + 1040
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000181885220 _pthread_body + 272
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000181885110 _pthread_body + 0
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000181883b10 thread_start + 4

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00000001816e5d84 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000181883eb4 _pthread_wqthread + 928
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000181883b08 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000181883b04 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00000001816e5d84 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x00000001818840a0 _pthread_wqthread + 1420
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000181883b08 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00000001816c3e5c semaphore_timedwait_trap + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001815530b0 _dispatch_sema4_timedwait$VARIANT$mp + 60
2   libdispatch.dylib              0x0000000181553924 _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 72
3   libdispatch.dylib              0x000000018155f23c _dispatch_worker_thread + 256
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000181885220 _pthread_body + 272
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000181885110 _pthread_body + 0
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000181883b10 thread_start + 4

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000181883b04 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00000001816c3e5c semaphore_timedwait_trap + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001815530b0 _dispatch_sema4_timedwait$VARIANT$mp + 60
2   libdispatch.dylib              0x0000000181553924 _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 72
3   libdispatch.dylib              0x000000018155f23c _dispatch_worker_thread + 256
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000181885220 _pthread_body + 272
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000181885110 _pthread_body + 0
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000181883b10 thread_start + 4

Thread 12 name:  WTF::AutomaticThread
Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00000001816e50f4 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000181887c90 _pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$mp + 644
2   JavaScriptCore                 0x00000001887cf310 WTF::ThreadCondition::timedWait+ 62224 (WTF::Mutex&, double) + 148
3   JavaScriptCore                 0x000000018926073c WTF::ParkingLot::parkConditionallyImpl(void const*, WTF::ScopedLambda<bool ()> const&, WTF::ScopedLambda<void + 11142972 ()> const&, WTF::TimeWithDynamicClockType const&) + 2252
4   JavaScriptCore                 0x0000000188d2124c bool WTF::Condition::waitUntil<WTF::Lock>+ 5640780 (WTF::Lock&, WTF::TimeWithDynamicClockType const&) + 184
5   JavaScriptCore                 0x0000000189245d18 WTF::Function<void ()>::CallableWrapper<WTF::AutomaticThread::start(WTF::AbstractLocker const&)::$_0>::call+ 11033880 () + 212
6   JavaScriptCore                 0x0000000189272024 WTF::Thread::entryPoint+ 11214884 (WTF::Thread::NewThreadContext*) + 224
7   JavaScriptCore                 0x00000001887ca9d4 WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint+ 43476 (void*) + 12
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000181885220 _pthread_body + 272
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000181885110 _pthread_body + 0
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000181883b10 thread_start + 4

Thread 13 name:  WTF::AutomaticThread
Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00000001816e50f4 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000181887c90 _pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$mp + 644
2   JavaScriptCore                 0x00000001887cf310 WTF::ThreadCondition::timedWait+ 62224 (WTF::Mutex&, double) + 148
3   JavaScriptCore                 0x000000018926073c WTF::ParkingLot::parkConditionallyImpl(void const*, WTF::ScopedLambda<bool ()> const&, WTF::ScopedLambda<void + 11142972 ()> const&, WTF::TimeWithDynamicClockType const&) + 2252
4   JavaScriptCore                 0x0000000188d2124c bool WTF::Condition::waitUntil<WTF::Lock>+ 5640780 (WTF::Lock&, WTF::TimeWithDynamicClockType const&) + 184
5   JavaScriptCore                 0x0000000189245d18 WTF::Function<void ()>::CallableWrapper<WTF::AutomaticThread::start(WTF::AbstractLocker const&)::$_0>::call+ 11033880 () + 212
6   JavaScriptCore                 0x0000000189272024 WTF::Thread::entryPoint+ 11214884 (WTF::Thread::NewThreadContext*) + 224
7   JavaScriptCore                 0x00000001887ca9d4 WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint+ 43476 (void*) + 12
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000181885220 _pthread_body + 272
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000181885110 _pthread_body + 0
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000181883b10 thread_start + 4

Thread 14:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00000001816c3e5c semaphore_timedwait_trap + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001815530b0 _dispatch_sema4_timedwait$VARIANT$mp + 60
2   libdispatch.dylib              0x0000000181553924 _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 72
3   libdispatch.dylib              0x000000018155f23c _dispatch_worker_thread + 256
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000181885220 _pthread_body + 272
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000181885110 _pthread_body + 0
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000181883b10 thread_start + 4

Thread 4 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000002   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000003   x3: 0x0000000000001002
    x4: 0x0000000035000000   x5: 0x0000000000000000   x6: 0x0000000100000000   x7: 0x0000000000000010
    x8: 0x0000000000000000   x9: 0x0000000000000000  x10: 0x0000000000000000  x11: 0x00000000000fffff
   x12: 0x000000000000000b  x13: 0x0000000000000001  x14: 0x0000000215dcf900  x15: 0x00000000e5952e6b
   x16: 0x00000000000000c5  x17: 0x000000000000006c  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x00000001b40e4930
   x20: 0x000000010b4991b0  x21: 0x0000000000000001  x22: 0x0000000000000000  x23: 0x0000000000000000
   x24: 0x000000020d9b9d68  x25: 0x0000000000000005  x26: 0x6d3a06d3a06d3a07  x27: 0x0000000000000001
   x28: 0x0000000000000258   fp: 0x000000016b47a010   lr: 0x000000018afb0c7c
    sp: 0x000000016b479fb0   pc: 0x000000018afb0d3c cpsr: 0x60000000
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you know what the url is?
Our app also encounter the same crash,it happend when people unzip file and then open the local html inside.

Comment: what is the solution to avoide this crash ?